# MATLAB initialize an array property

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a class called class_geometry which hold the geometric quantities of each cells in a grid. On of these quantities is the x location of each of the four corners of the cell. I then make initialize an array of these class objects (not sure if my terminology is correct). 
My problem is that I do not know how to initialize an array in my class def. Here is my class:

```
classdef class_geometry
    properties
        dx1;
        dx2;
        dx3;
        dx4;
    end
end
```

And I would like to have just dx that holds four different values:

```
classdef class_geometry
    properties
        dx;
    end
end
```

So in the end I could do something like that:

```
for i = 1:IL+1
    for j = 1:JL+1
        cell(i,j).dx(1) = x_grid(i+1,j)   - x_grid(i,j);
        cell(i,j).dx(2) = x_grid(i+1,j+1) - x_grid(i+1,j);
        cell(i,j).dx(3) = x_grid(i,j+1)   - x_grid(i+1,j+1);
        cell(i,j).dx(4) = x_grid(i,j)     - x_grid(i,j+1);
    end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want to avoid the cycle, right?

Comment: ya pretty much. I'll also have other properties like dy, dS, dn who all have 4 values assign to them. It'll make the code easier to read and implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is to initialize an array *inside* the class, you have to define a [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29). The constructor is called when you initialize your object and aims at allocating memory for object members.

Here is how you can initialize and empty array for `dx`

```
   classdef class_geometry
       methods

         function obj = class_geometry()   //Constructor function
             obj.dx = zeros(1,4);   //because you had 4 entries
             ...

         end

        end
        .....
   end
```

Moreover, if you want to initialize the values `dx` contains in the constructor, you have to pass it the index/indices of the current grid cell

```
       function obj = class_geometry(i,j)   //Constructor function, 2nd version
                                            //i,j indices of the cell
             obj.dx = zeros(1,4);   //because you had 4 entries
              dx(1) = x_grid(i+1,j)   - x_grid(i,j);
              dx(2) = x_grid(i+1,j+1) - x_grid(i+1,j);
              dx(3) = x_grid(i,j+1)   - x_grid(i+1,j+1);
              dx(4) = x_grid(i,j)     - x_grid(i,j+1);

       end
```

Now, you can initialize your cells as

```
      cell(i,j) = class_geometry(i,j); //forall i,j.
```

---

Instead, if the problem is the *initialization of array of objects*, you may want to consider [this reference](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html#bsw8dee).

---

Finally, my humble guess is that the vectorization you are trying is sub-optimal.

Because you have your grid in the matrix `x_grid`, a vectorization like (for the first case)

```
  dx_1 = diff(x_grid,1,1); //computes x_grid(i+1,j) - x_grid(i,j); 
                           //forall i,j producing the difference matrix
```

would be more efficient. It would save you a lot of *external* cycles (wrt the class).

Comment: Thanks for your input. This helps for this case but I also need in another part of my code to have a property array for my primitive variables U. If you could just tell me how to set up a array in a class that would be great! So in this case instead of cell(i,j).dx_1 = diff(x_grid,1,1) I would have cell(i,j).dx(1) = diff(x_grid,1,1)

Comment: @user1236187, well, the correct version of your statement would be ` cell(:,:).dx(1) = diff(x_grid,1,1)` but frankly I doubt matlab does support it. Let me have a look.

Comment: @user1236187, please consider the answer now

Comment: That's perfect! It's exactly what I was looking for thanks! Just a last question, you were talking about efficiency earlier, is this considered to be inefficient in terms of running time? I am doing a CFD code on the euler equations, I would like my code so be a minimum efficient.

Comment: Nice!! :) -- may you consider to accept the answer? ;). Well, AFAIK matlab is not very efficient in OOP. Moreover, you should try to vectorize as much as you can, meaning you should try to logically wrap things in arrays so that you can express your operations in terms of vector operations (matlab has fast core compiled functions for that).

Comment: @user1236187, please consider the last comment I put.